# Burning iso to DVD - find device

Tags: iso, burning

I am trying to burn an iso-file to a DVD but I am new to this and cannot fully accomplish it.

I have the following iso:

```
myiso/myfirst.iso
```

and then I look up the device to burn to:

```
inxi -d
```

the followinig information is produced:

```
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (3.7% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: ST1000DM003 size: 1000.2GB 
       Optical: /dev/sr0 model: N/A dev-links: cdrom
       Features: speed: 48x multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,c
```

So which dev-name should I use? is it sda? i tried to burn with the following command:

```
 wodim -eject -tao speed=2 dev=/dev/sda -v -data myfirst.iso
```

as a first step, but I get the following error:

```
 TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
```

scsidev: '/dev/sda'
devname: '/dev/sda'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2

```
Error trying to open /dev/sda exclusively (Device or resource busy)... retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sda exclusively (Device or resource busy)... retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sda exclusively (Device or resource busy)... retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sda exclusively (Device or resource busy)...   retrying in 1 second.
Error trying to open /dev/sda exclusively (Device or resource busy)... giving up.
wodim: Device or resource busy. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

I have even tried with:

```
growisofs -Z /dev/dvdrw=myfirst.iso
```

which produces:

```
:-( "/dev/dvdrw=myfirst.iso": unexpected errno:No such file or directory
```

So - What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Optical: /dev/sr0 `, therefore use `/dev/sr0` in `wodim`.

Comment: @garethTheRed - then I get the following error: _WARNING: /dev/sr0 seems to be mounted!
wodim: Device or resource busy. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!_

Comment: What distro are you using? Does running `mount` show the device as mounted anywhere? If so, try un-mounting it with `sudo umount /dev/sr0`.

Comment: @garethTheRed using ubuntu. Thanks, now somethings happends. How do I mount it again? _Now it cannot find sr0_

Comment: `brasero` is installed by default on Ubuntu.  It's a nice GUI for burning optical media. Give it a try.

Comment: The brasero that is delivered by Ubuntu is not usable as it does not use cdrtools.

Answer (score 0):

I have had excellent results using Brasero, which comes installed on Ubuntu and Mint. However, I respect you for trying to learn how to accomplish this using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

> So which dev-name should I use? is it sda?

No. `inxi` reports your **hard drive** as `/dev/sda`, and the **optical drive** as `/dev/sr0` (also symlinked to `/dev/cdrom`):

```
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (3.7% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: ST1000DM003 size: 1000.2GB 
       Optical: /dev/sr0 model: N/A dev-links: cdrom
       Features: speed: 48x multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,c
```

That's because `inxi -d` also includes `inxi -D`, which reports hard drives. Either way, the correct `wodim` `dev` parameter is therefore `/dev/sr0` and the wodim command should be

```
wodim dev=/dev/sr0 <other options> path/to/your.iso
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use wodim, as it is a dead and buggy fork made from a cdrecord from May 2004. Wodim also in general cannot write DVDs because there is no working DVD driver inside.

With a recent cdrecord, you no not need to specify a device at all in case that you just have one drive in you system. BTW: the original cdrtools sources have got many new features since May 2004 and aproximately give you twice as many fatures as you get with that wodim.

The message you posted is showing one of 100 well documented bugs in wodim. You will not run into that problem when using the original cdrecord.

Fortunately all decent Linux distros deliver a decent cdrtools based installation. If you are using one of the user-unfriendly Linux distros, you need to compile it yourself from sources.

The source is here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrtools/files/

Comment: how do I integrate it in brasero

Comment: If you use an unmodified brasero, it is integrated. The problem is the brasero variant Created by Debian and used by Debian followers.  BTW: there is a private person who creates cdrtools binary install packages for Ubuntu - maybe he knows what do do here.

Comment: Found the name: Search for the packages from Brandon Snider for Ubuntu.